# Keydown on up arrow not preventing default, still makes div scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a chat area, where messages go, and a chat input below. As you can see in this structure:

[image]

After load I run this function:

```
function activate_key_detection()
{
    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        if(e.ctrlKey)
        {
            if(window.getSelection().toString() != "")
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        $('#chat_input').focus();

        if(code == 13)
        {
            send_to_chat();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        if(code == 38)
        {
            $('#chat_input').val(last_input);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        if(code == 27)
        {
            if($('#overlay').css('display') == 'block')
            {
                hide_boxes();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                clear_input();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

As you can see it first focuses the input, and when the key is the up arrow (38) it catches it, modifies the input and tries to prevent the default behavior of they key.

The problem is, when I first click inside the chat area, and then press the up arrow, it will still scroll the chat area a line. Subsequent presses of the up arrow don't scroll the chat area further.

I tried adding e.stopPropagation() there too, to no avail.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I don't know, it seems to work fine for me in firefox, but there's also `stopImmediatePropagation` and `cancelBubble`

Comment: cancelBubble seems to be deprecated. stopImmediatePropagation didn't seem to work, either after or before preventDefault. One thing I forgot to mention is that some elements in the chat area are added dynamically after I run the activate_key_detection function, so maybe they're not affected by it? idk

Comment: the listener is on `$(document)` so I would assume dynamic content is not an issue - does the code get run at all the first time? (console.log for debugging would be good here)

Comment: Yes the code gets run, because the chat input gets the text change and console.logs do fire

Comment: I think maybe the default scrolling event is triggering before my custom keydown event

Comment: I'm going to do something different with the up arrow, so this is not a problem for me now, thanks